# How do I schedule a pthread_cond_signal() such that it always follows a pthread_cond_wait() on another thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am testing a producer-consumer scenario where the producer blocks when it tries to write on a queue which is full. I want to test that the producer thread wakes up properly and works as per expectation after the consumer reads from the full queue*. The queue write API calls pthread_cond_wait() on detecting queue full and the read API signals the conditional variable after reading from the queue.

How do I ensure the occurrence of **Sequence 3** over any other sequence of operations in my test environment?

[image]

* *Yes I want to test this limited scenario separately; there are other tests which do test the functionality of the whole queue, this test is in addition to those.*

> More details -
>   There is a single mutex governing the queue. There
>   are 2 conditional variables - one to signal write (all writes), one to
>   signal read (all reads). The **queue_write API blocks on the read
>   condvar** if the queue is full. The **queue_read API blocks on the
>   write condvar** if the queue is empty. All signalling happens under
>   the aegis of the mutex.
>   *There is a lot more nuance in the queue but
>   for the purpose of setting context for this question this is an
>   adequate summary of the queue's functioning.*

Comment: Only start the producer thread, wait until it is blocked, then start the consumer?

Comment: Are there any API functions which lets you just test whenever the queue is full?

Comment: @EOF - How do I programmatically find out that the producer thread is now blocked? (I am looking for something beyond "*wait for an adequate amount of time*")

Comment: @Superlokkus - There is.

Comment: So what's the signature of the testing function? Would help very much for referring in an answer.

Comment: @Superlokkus - You mean the queue write API? Or did you actually mean testing function? (TBH, I don't see how it would help).

Comment: @work.bin: Have the producer `pthread_cond_signal()` a thread `_cond_wait()`ing to become the consumer as it blocks?

Comment: I mean something like `bool is_queue_full(const my_queue*)`

Comment: @EOF - Isn't there a posibility that the `_cond_wait() ing` thread could commence the read without the producer thread proceeding from the pthread_cond_signal() to the subsequent pthread_cond_wait()? (I am not sure). Anyway, ideally I would like to keep the API function untouched, this _cond_signal() will have to be under same mutex lock used for cond_wait() inside the producer write API.

Comment: @Superlokkus - There is a similar function which returns a boolean.

Comment: As I said in a comment to my answer and due to the new bounty: I would really appreciate if you could name all mutexes and condition variables you use.

Comment: @Superlokkus - Edited the question to provide more details. Pray do tell if this is enough information.

Comment: Checkout the edit of my answer

Comment: An accepted mark for either jxh or my answer would be nice. Or in other words: gimme that sweet reputation, now! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since your queue uses `pthread_cond_signal`, it must be holding a lock as well. So your test case should simply hold the lock, create the producer, and then wait for the signal. After the producer generates the signal, release the lock, and create a consumer.

```
void test () {
    pthread_mutex_lock(q_lock);
    //     Blocks on the same queue lock the producer and
    //     consumer would use.
    create_producer();
    //     The producer will block on the queue lock when
    //     it tries to write to the queue.
    do {
        pthread_cond_wait(q_write_cond, q_lock);
        // Mimic a blocked queue_read, and wait for the
        // producer to signal. This will release the lock
        // and allow the producer to progress.
    } while (!q_is_full());
    //     The queue is now full, lock is held since
    //     pthread_cond_wait returned.
    pthread_mutex_unlock(q_lock);
    //     Release the queue lock, allow the consumer to
    //     operate unhindered.
    create_consumer();
    //     The consumer will proceed to drain the queue.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** (Be aware that error handling of the pthread calls were omitted)

You can achieve this by testing if the queue is full, with the function you mentioned in the comments. For this answer I will assume it's `bool is_queue_full(const queue*)`.

In your test case you can guarantee scenario 3, by creating the producer and create a consumer, if and only if, after the queue is full. Like
    bool is_queue_full(queue*); //Must not use the mutex itself, maybe mark it just for intern use

```
struct queue {
    /* Actual queue stuff */
    pthread_mutex_t queue_mutex;
    pthread_cond_t read_condvar;
    pthread_cond_t write_condvar;
};

void wait_until_queue_is_full (queue *q) {

    pthread_mutex_lock(&q->queue_mutex);
    while (!is_queue_full(q)){ //Use in loop because of Spurious wakeups
        pthread_cond_wait(&q->write_condvar,&q->queue_mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->queue_mutex);
}

bool test_writer_woke_up(queue *q);

bool test_case(){
    queue *q = create_queue();
    producer *p = create_producer(q);

    wait_until_queue_is_full(q);

    return test_writer_woke_up(q); //or cache the result and destroy your queue, but if your testrunner process will quit anyway...
}
```

`wait_until_queue_is_full` will just check if the queue is full, and if not, will wait, like any reader, until your writer aka producer has made it full. Then your testcase can produce the consumers with something like `test_writer_woke_up`
    void intern_consume_stuff(queue *q); /* Your intern function that takes stuff from the queue, 
    but doesen't care about the sychronization aka mutexes and condvar*/

```
bool test_writer_woke_up(queue *q){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&q->queue_mutex); //Could be omitted in this testcase (together with the 1 unlock below of course)
    void intern_consume_stuff(queue *q);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->queue_mutex); //Could be omitted in this testcase (together with the 1 lock above of course)
    pthread_cond_signal(&q->read_condvar);

    /* Adjust these as you like to give your producer/writer time to wake up and produce something 
    */
    unsigned retry_count = 5;
    unsigned sleep_time = 1; 

    //timed cond wait approach
    for (; retry_count > 0; --retry_count){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&q->queue_mutex);
        struct timespec ts;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
        ts.tv_sec += sleep_time;
        int timed_cond_rc = 0;
        while (!is_queue_full(q) && timed_cond_rc == 0) {
            timed_cond_rc = pthread_cond_timedwait(&q->write_condvar, &q->queue_mutex, &ts);
        }
        if (is_queue_full(q)) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->queue_mutex);
            return true;
        }
        assert(timed_cond_rc == ETIMEDOUT);
        continue;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If have used the absolute time waiting, because you had to recompute relative timings, or to simplify things you could replace the for loop with this naive approach

```
//naive busy approach
for (; retry_count > 0; --retry_count){
    pthread_mutex_lock(q->queue_mutex);
    const bool queue_full_result = is_queue_full(q);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(q->queue_mutex);

    if (queue_full_result){
        return true;
    } else {
        pthread_yield();
        sleep(sleep_time);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have considered this but abandoned this idea since I thought this was CPU intensive. I wanted a cleaner way to achieve this i.e. not busy-read the queue status.

Comment: This is only achievable if you can want to or are allowed to or able to write your own `is_queue_full`. Also that busy-waiting shouldn't be that bad in your non-productive test-code. But since this seems to be your own queue, we could write an async approach. Could you give me the names of your mutexes and condition to check the "fullness"?

Comment: I am kind of arriving at the conclusion that there is no proper way of doing this without having to modify the Queue APIs itself. Therefore I would prefer the above method. However I want to consider your opinion on `while (!is_queue_full(q)) pthread_yield();` - is this an improvement?

Comment: @work.bin Could be, but I guess it actually depends on your system, because it has a advantage but also one disadvantage.
Pro: Gives the schedeuler a hint to give the CPU to other tasks, i.e. your producers
Con: You will call a whole function every loop iteration. The overhead to call a function alone are a handfull machine instructions, yet the maybe complex `pthread_yield()` body.

I personally would just stick to `while (!is_queue_full(q));` because the next logical step would be just to avoid busy waiting. But it's worth to profile/measure.

Comment: I changed my default advice to recommend your way, with `while (!is_queue_full(q)) pthread_yield();`,due this approach is AFAIK more likely to prevent *priority inversion*